# Git Command for Launch Rebase After Fetch

Tags: git, tortoise-git

Is there any way I can use command for "Launch Rebase After Fetch" instead check the box ON from Git dialog?

Answer (score 0):

For TortoiseGit there is no command switch for activating this (as of 2.9.0).